# How to save / downloaded embedded m3u8 or video files with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, download, m3u8

I would like to see if its possible to download embedded `m3u8` files with Firefox. Here is a sample link https://play.vidyard.com/hHWGJb8vbRheMYy4u8J5Z2 . When the link is opened in browser, the video will play without any problem. I used [Video Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) to analyze the link and I got the below details (removed some irrelevant details);

- extension: m3u8
- title: video-kibana-login-spaces-710
- topUrl: https://play.vidyard.com/hHWGJb8vbRheMYy4u8J5Z2
- url: https://cdn.vidyard.com/hls-videos/l3BRu0bLwduq7RrY9-8o4w/stream_master_RvrdhY21smFlRUx-al76hA.m3u8?Bt8AyuJk5cmH1Vda-yr-I48M-m6A5nlRFcbZeMWL8ycWLZu9cj78JpEXpprgfcMZg5T9ttl0MzxN5bNh5L3-MCh-xp9OgNqVviw28ov9Ba0Gx5xYKW_25py8XUvAK-iiNpl5LaNLZr8vGC7sMxiKmQnj_P9c-lq917KKjVgHVyvbrwJrNjh_VfIRHGttKeRJ2Mg_
- urlFilename: stream_master_RvrdhY21smFlRUx-al76hA

And I used Firefox Developer Console and got below details;

[image: Screenshot]

I can see that .ts file is associated, and the status is "cached". But, under cache tab, nothing is available. Is it possible to download such a file?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to download single segments or the entire set of segments for a video?

Comment: hi @jmsn I am looking for a way to get the entire video

Comment: That could prove difficult if you want to do it "manually", as you'd need to do some HLS playlist handling, segment URL resolving, etc. Does it have to be within Firefox? Also, I would think there are browser extensions that support this.